# Elasticsearch Query where KEY is Null

Tags: elasticsearch

Im having problems getting a query to return the results i require. Im wanting to search for all documents which have a Field name called 'Title' but only them where the value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Elasticsearch does not store fields with `null` value in its index, so you are not able to distinguish documents without `Title` field at all from documents where this field contains `null`. To cope with this issue you have explicitly choose some value that will indicate that field is empty. Look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html) article for details.